# Let p,q, r be fixed elements of a Field F

Tags: vector-spaces

Let  $p,q,r$ be the fixed elements of a field $F$ .  Let 
$$W=\{(x,y,z) \in V^3(F)|px+qy+rz=0\}$$
Prove that $W(F)$  is a vector sub-space of $V^3(F)$ .

I think i need to satisfy these conditions but I am not sure though

(i) W is non-empty
(ii) closed under scalar multiplicaton
(iii)closed under vector addition

Should I proceed this way??

Comment: Almost - for (i) you mean that the zero vector of $V$ is in $W$.  Then, yes, proceed that way.

Comment: @Lost, (i) as stated is fine in the presence of (ii) and (iii) because $0=v-v$.

Comment: @lhf, Alright, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I have solved it like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have found the answer, but just to add something more; showing $W$ is non-empty is obvious as clearly $0\in W$. Conditions (2) and (3) could also be written as a single step,

$$\alpha w_1+\beta w_2\in W\,\forall \alpha,\,\beta\in\mathbb{F}\mbox{ and }\forall w_1,\,w_2\in W$$

So essentially you can take any two elements $w_1$ and $w_2$ from $W$ and any two elements $\alpha,\,\beta\in\mathbb{F}$ and show that $\alpha w_1+\beta w_2\in W$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped me

Comment: You are very welcome. :)